# How to add radio button for select the row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to add `radio button` for selecting the entire row which is data coming from the `database`. 
Data comes in the table format. so i want to show radio button in first colomn.
and with this radio check button and can do Action.
please do need full.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
                       {

                    <div class="row footable_box">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <div align="center">  <span id="spn_message" style="color:green;font:bolder;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" ></span></div>
                            <table id="demo-foo-filtering" class="table table-bordered table-hover toggle-circle" data-page-size="10">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th data-toggle="true" data-sort-ignore="true" style="text-align:center">Booking ID</th>
                                        <th data-sort-ignore="true" style="text-align:center">
                                            Service Provider Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">Service Name</th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true" style="text-align:center" width="18%">Comsumer Name</th>
                                        @*<th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">
                                            Booked on <br />
                                            Date & Time
                                        </th>*@
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">
                                            Service <br />
                                            Start Date
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">
                                            Service <br />
                                            End Date
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">
                                            Service <br />
                                            Start Time
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">
                                            Service <br />
                                            End Time
                                        </th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true"  style="text-align:center">Status</th>
                                        <th data-hide="phone, tablet" data-sort-ignore="true" width="10%"  style="text-align:center">View Service</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>



                                    @foreach (var CAH in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            @*<td><input type="radio" style="text-align:center" name="row" value="@CAH.BookingID"></input></td>*@
                                           <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.BookingID</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.Provider</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.Service</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.Consumer</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.StartDate</td> 
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.EndDate</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.StartTime</td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.EndTime</td>
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So what is your question realy? U want a radiobutton in the first column? Just do the thing below. Does this help? Have in your model a property BookingID that can catch it on the post method.

```
 @foreach (var CAH in Model)
 {
      <tr>
           <td>@Html.RadioButton("BookingID",@CAH.BookingID)</td>  
           <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.BookingID</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.Provider</td>
           <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.Service</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.Consumer</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.StartDate</td> 
            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.EndDate</td>
          <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.StartTime</td>
            <td style="text-align:center">@CAH.EndTime</td>
  }
```

Comment: radio button its not in database when data display then the button should come

Comment: What is not working? What did u try? How does your Index Post looks like? What parameters are there? What is it you are asking?

Comment: Not helping at all. What do u want to happen? How does it need to look like and how should it work?